# How to host .NET Core webapp in MacBook Pro using apache?

Tags: macos, localhost, .net-core

I have created a simple .NET Core webapplication in mac using Visual studio for mac. Now want to test the application by hosting it locally.

Is it possible to host the application in mac? If yes, please share me the steps or any useful links to host the appliation using Nginx or Apache http in mac.

For Windows, I have used Local IIS to host and test the application in local server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the appropriate SDK installed, its as simple as calling [`dotnet run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore2x) from your source directory

Comment: dotnet run working fine in developement. But now I want to host the app using apache or nginx or other server in macbook.

Comment: Publish, run, and reverse proxy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: The above blog has steps for linux, not for macbook.

Comment: Yes, but it outlines what steps you need to take does it not? Publish, run and reverse proxy. For all intents and purposes, the tooling available in macOS is equivalent to a linux install.